# Java Swing JPanel rapaint doesn't call paintcomponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I have the following code:

```
package de.luiskun.handling;

import de.luiskun.UtilityTool;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class PixelArtCreator extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    BufferedImage imgBefore;
    Thread gameThread;

    public static final int width = 900, height = 500;

    int fps = 60;

    public PixelArtCreator() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        imgBefore = UtilityTool.SetupImage("res/preparation/00001", 512, 512);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println(1);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(imgBefore != null) {
            g2.drawImage(imgBefore, 10, 10, 512, 512, null);
        }
    }

    public void startGameThread() {
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000 / fps; // 0.0166s
        double delta = 0;
        double lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double currentTime;
        while (gameThread != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            lastTime = currentTime;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                System.out.println(2);
                //update();
                this.repaint();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main class:

```
package de.luiskun;

import de.luiskun.handling.PixelArtCreator;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(PixelArtCreator.width+14, PixelArtCreator.height+38);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        PixelArtCreator s = new PixelArtCreator();
        frame.add(s);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        s.setUpTimer();
    }

}
```

In the main method I create a JFrame and thenn add the PixelArtCreator. Then i call startGameThread.

The console only prints out '2', but not '1'. I dont know why repaint doesnt call paintcomponent.

I used this code in many projects, but now it strangely doesnt work anymore.

Comment: The delta gameloop works, but I recommend using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead. The delta game loop can be really CPU intensive.

Comment: I just tried using a Timer, but repaint is still not getting called

Comment: Invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` at the top of your `paintComponent` method

Comment: Doesn't fix it either :(
But I will keep it in

Comment: I added the main class to the question, maybe the error is somewhere there

Comment: I changed setPreferredSize to setBounds(0,0,width,height) and not it works. But someone said some time ago, that i shouldn't use setBounds

Comment: Hmm running this code by adding the panel to a JFrame then starting its thread seems to work fine for me

Comment: You havent replaced your code to include the timer btw ;)

Comment: My code works fine now. I changed some things in the Main Class that were different to my other projects. I will upload the solution now. Maybe you see the problem from before.

Comment: `setLayout(null);` is most often a secure sign that something is wrong... Without a `LayoutManager` you must write code to set the correct location and **size** of the component(s) (not the preferred size, which would be used by the `LayoutManager`). Since no size is set, the default is 0x0, that is, nothing is being displayed, so there is no need to call any painting method. || posted code is not a [mre], not complete, I could not test it, but try changing `setPreferredSize` to `setSize` - and then, instead of that, consider using a `LayoutManager`

Answer (score 0):

I changed some things in the Main method and now it works. But I didnt found the problem from before.

```
package de.luiskun;

import de.luiskun.handling.PixelArtCreator;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        PixelArtCreator pac = new PixelArtCreator();
        window.add(pac);

        window.pack();

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        pac.startTimer();
    }

}
```

```
package de.luiskun.handling;

import de.luiskun.UtilityTool;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class PixelArtCreator extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage imgBefore;
    Thread gameThread;
    Timer timer;

    public static final int width = 900, height = 532;

    int fps = 60;

    public PixelArtCreator() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        // this.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        imgBefore = UtilityTool.SetupImage("res/preparation/00001", 512, 512);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(imgBefore != null) {
            g2.drawImage(imgBefore, 10, 10, 512, 512, null);
        }
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(10,new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```